# Executing gcloud command in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, gcloud

I'm trying to run the gcloud command in a Jenkins declarative pipeline just like in the following example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

   stages {
      stage('Run gcloud version') {

         steps {
            sh 'gcloud --version'           
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I downloaded the "GCloud SDK Plugin" and configured it like this (in "Global Tool Configuration" for Jenkins):

[image]

but when I try to build the pipeline using the above Jenkinsfile, I'm getting a 'gcloud: not found' error in the pipeline.

Comment: set PATH variable of jenkins user to include the path where gcloud is currently located. `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin` in jenkins users .bash_profile

Comment: Sorry, can you be more specific? I  cannot find users .bash_profile in Jenkins

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to run the command using the following Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
   agent any

stages {
    stage('Run gcloud') {

        steps {
            withEnv(['GCLOUD_PATH=/var/jenkins_home/google-cloud-sdk/bin']) {
                sh '$GCLOUD_PATH/gcloud --version'
            }


         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note: I'm running Jenkins in kubernetes, so first I had to install the gcloud sdk in the Jenkins pod

Comment: I was trying the path like /var/lib/jenkins/google-cloud-sdk/bin where /var/lib/jenkins is m the home directory showing under Configure System screen. However getting gcloud - command not found. Any suggestions here?

Answer (score 1):

I am running Jenkins 2.176.2 in containers and the GCloud plugin was not able to install the SDK in the slave (agents) containers.
I used the docker file to install it when deploying the agents:

```
RUN echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk-stretch main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list \
    && curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add - \
    && apt-get update -y && apt-get install google-cloud-sdk -y \
    && PATH=$PATH:/root/google-cloud-sdk/bin
```