# using gcloud in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gcloud

I use Jenkins installed on GKE.
I installed GCloud SDK Plugin and configured it with Global Tool Configuration.
When I use gcloud in my pipeline I receive "not found" error.
I tried the solution recommended in [Executing gcloud command in Jenkins pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948534/executing-gcloud-command-in-jenkins-pipeline).

```
pipeline {
   agent any

stages {
    stage('Run gcloud') {

        steps {
            withEnv(['GCLOUD_PATH=/var/jenkins_home/google-cloud-sdk/bin']) {
                sh '$GCLOUD_PATH/gcloud --version'
            }


         }
      }
   }
}
```

But there is no "jenkins_home" in my /var directory.

```
+ ls -l /var/
total 36
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Jun 26  2018 backups
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Oct 29  2018 cache
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Oct 16  2018 lib
drwxrwsr-x 2 root staff 4096 Jun 26  2018 local
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     9 Oct 11  2018 lock -> /run/lock
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Oct 29  2018 log
drwxrwsr-x 2 root mail  4096 Oct 11  2018 mail
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct 11  2018 opt
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     4 Oct 11  2018 run -> /run
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Oct 11  2018 spool
drwxrwxrwt 2 root root  4096 Jun 26  2018 tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
stage('Deploy'){
    steps{

        //Deploy to GCP
        sh """
            #!/bin/bash 
            echo "deploy stage";
            curl -o /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-225.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz;
            tar -xvf /tmp/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz -C /tmp/;
            /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh -q;

                        source /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc;


             gcloud config set project ${GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID};
             gcloud components install app-engine-java;
             gcloud components install app-engine-python;
             gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ${GOOGLE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY};

             gcloud config list;
             gcloud app deploy --version=v01;
                         echo "Deployed to GCP"
        """
        }   

}
```

Comment: Does it mean that I have to install the SDK  for every job or I do it once?

Comment: What is "source /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc;"  in your script?

Comment: I have a service account key on my PC. How can I upload it to Jenkins?

Comment: hey @BT3 , check [this article](https://medium.com/@sportans300/jenkins-pipeline-to-deploy-angular-app-to-appengine-gcp-1f58160e2779) for more info on the subject

Comment: another option would be is to connect to one of your container and locate the cloud sdk in the container using `kubectl exec POD_NAME -c CONTAINER_NAME -- echo $PATH`. copy the full location of the cloud SDK and use it in your initial solution.