# gcloud - command not found in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, gcloud

I am trying to build a pipeline with gcloud commands to create cluster, deploy apps, etc. but couldn't do it as getting the error **gcloud - command not found**

Tried to refer some SO links but no luck. I can see the GCloud SDK plug-in was installed in my Jenkins instance as shown below, and tried to set the Environment variable and directly passing like below too..

[image: GCloud SDK Installed]

```
withEnv(['GCLOUD_PATH=/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/gcloud-sdk/']) {
            sh '$GCLOUD_PATH/gcloud --version'
        }
```

still command not found error. Not sure what I am doing wrong or missing any. Appreciate any inputs on this.

Comment: See [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54949410/609290). `GCLOUD_PATH` needs to point to an installation of [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install). It appears that the plugin merely wraps the underlying installation

Comment: @DazWilkin given the directory output that Shan shared, which of those files in WEB-INF or META-INF should be pointed to in order to work?

Comment: @juanddiaz13 none of them. Per my comment, the plugin only wraps `gcloud`; you need to install `gcloud` separately to use the plugin.